# How can I combine commit using git rebase

Tags: git

How can I combine 1st commit with 4th commit in git using 'git rebase'.
From what I read here http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html, the 'squash' command in 'git rebase' only meld into previous commit.

in git, I have

```
$ git log
commit 9a30d13
commit 4a6729e
commit 4a6729e
commit 4a6729e
commit a610898
```

Basically, I want changes from 9a30d13 to combine with changes in a610898, so that the new history is

```
$ git log
commit 4a6729e
commit 4a6729e
commit 4a6729e
commit a610898 + 9a30d13
```

I have not pushed anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do an interactive rebase as described at your link, you can *reorder* the commits, too.  Once you change the order, you can squash `9a30d13` into `a610898`.

When the interactive rebase comes up, it will look something like this (with the oldest commits on top):

```
pick a610898 Message A
pick 4a6729e Message B
pick 4a6729e Message C
pick 4a6729e Message D
pick 9a30d13 Message E
```

You then reorder them:

```
pick a610898 Message A
pick 9a30d13 Message E
pick 4a6729e Message B
pick 4a6729e Message C
pick 4a6729e Message D
```

And change `9a30d13` to `squash` rather than `pick`:

```
pick a610898 Message A
squash 9a30d13 Message E
pick 4a6729e Message B
pick 4a6729e Message C
pick 4a6729e Message D
```

Save & exit, and you're done.  You'll get a chance to enter a new commit message for your new `a610898` + `9a30d13` commit.

Comment: @0x90, what does that mean?

Comment: I meant if you could publish all commands and outputs from shell, but it looks like you did it. did you mean to use git before each line?

Comment: no – what you are seeing there is the editor you get when you run `git rebase --interactive **somesha**`