# How can I use rebase -i so that one commit contains changes of another one?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

Consider this situation. I have 5 commits A-B-C-D-E. I want to use rebase -i so that commit B will have all changes of commit D. How can I do that ?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine commit using git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676517/how-can-i-combine-commit-using-git-rebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git rebase -i A
```

The editor pops with the content:

```
pick B
pick C
pick D
pick E
```

Edit the content:

```
pick B
squash D
pick C
pick E
```

Save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `git rebase -i HEAD~4` and then you will see

```
pick ae2c481 B
pick 2b1007f C
pick bcda8c5 D
pick 8591cea E

# Rebase 69f1cd1..8591cea onto 69f1cd1 (4 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

then do

```
pick ae2c481 B
squash bcda8c5 D
pick 2b1007f C
pick 8591cea E
```

Comment: Thanks btw I wanted to ask one more thing. Consider the same I have commits A-B-C-D-E. Commit D added to my code for example one class. But I want from commit B to contain that change and delete this change in commit D. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want a part of commit D in commit B ?